# UIScrollView contents take several seconds to update via swipe gesture

Tags: ios

I have a UIScrollView inside which I have a UIView which has 5 UITextViews. All this works fine and I'm able to scroll up and down. I have a UISwipeGestureRecognizer connected to the UIScrollView programatically.

When I receive a swipe notification I update the contents of the 5 text views. However it takes upto 30 seconds for the updated text to actually appear. If I update the contents of the 5 text views inside a button press handler, they update immediately.

I have tried calling setNeedsDisplay() on scrollView as well as contentView. This did not help. I also tried scrolling the scrollView programatically, and that did not help either. I have verified that the swipe gesture handler is running in the same thread as the UI.

This the code inside my viewDidLoad()

```
let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))
let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipes(_:)))

leftSwipe.direction = .left
rightSwipe.direction = .right
view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
```

And these are my callbacks

```
@objc func handleSwipes(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
{
    if sender.direction == .left
    {
        print("swipe left")
    }
    else if sender.direction == .right
    {
        print("swipe right")
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you receiving the swipe notification?

Comment: I have updated my question to include the swipe code

Comment: does the scroll view scroll horizontally? Is it only the updating of text that is delayed? Or is the swipe gesture getting triggered that is delayed?

Comment: yes, it scrolls horizontally. Vertical scroll is disabled.

Comment: swipe recognizer might not be triggered all the time then, as it conflicts with scroll view pan recognizer

Comment: I have added prints in my code that indicate that swipe is being recognized immediately each time I swipe.

Comment: sorry, can't replicate the delay in updating text view text

Comment: Although I have still not resolved this issue, I realized that my approach was wrong. I should use UIPageViewController to get the job done